# How to include this jQuery File in wordpress?

Tags: plugins, php, jquery, html

Ok I have this jQuery that I have tested in a static html page and it works fine.

How would I include jQuery to work on wordpress in a plugin?

So this is the html page.

```
<head>
<title> Welcome to my page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css">
</head>
<body>


<a id="word" href="#">Google</a>
<span id="hoovertext"> a powerful search engine</span>


</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/hide.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</body>
```

SO this is the jQuery file that works for this html page

```
$('a').mousemove(function(){

    $('#hoovertext').show();

});

$('#hoovertext').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut();

});
```

Basically I want this jQuery to work on specific words on my wordpress site.. in the sense that when somebody hovers mouse over text it gives a description. exactly what my code above does.

Can somebody please show me how, since I including jQuery into wordpress is the one thing that I still don't quite understand.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Including jQuery in Wordpress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14205/including-jquery-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `wp_register_script()` and `wp_enqueue_script()`, so, for example:

```
add_action( 'wp_enquque_scripts', 'my_script_enqueue' );

function my_script_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-jquery', 'URL TO THE FILE', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
```

Also, as mentioned by Zack, you should be registering your jQuery as such, as wordpress does not use `$` for jQuery by default.

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    //your jquery
});
```

Comment: was going to answer, but this is pretty much exactly what i was going to say.  perfect answer, imo.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script). Although, I just noticed you are using the `$` prefix.

Try to do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   (function($) {
      // my javascript/jquery here
   })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Basically, I forget the technical reason why you have to do this, but something with `$` being using already by another javascript library. What this code does is create an anonymous function that takes a parameter of "`$`". This function also passes the jQuery object to it so, in essence, `$` is jQuery again, for this function.

**EDIT:** Thanks to Chip in the comments, the technical reason is because jQuery with WordPress is running in [no conflict mode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers).

Comment: The "technical reason" is that [WordPress uses **no-conflict** mode for jQuery](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers); so `$` is not available by default as a shorthand for `jQuery`. Try using `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {`.