# Adding the jQuery to my theme that already exists in Wordpress?

Tags: themes, jquery

I'm working on a custom theme in which it uses a custom script loaded like so in the functions.php file:

```
function custom_scripts_method()
{
        wp_register_script('custom_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('custom_script');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts_method');
```

I need jQuery to get it to run properly, I tried to enqueue the already existing jQuery with:

```
function theme_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts');
```

As answered in this question here: [Is jQuery included in WordPress by default?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/140307/is-jquery-included-in-wordpress-by-default)

However, this does nothing. So I added my own jQuery like so:

```
function jquery_scripts_method()
{
        wp_register_script('jquery_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.1', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery_script');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jquery_scripts_method');
```

That worked, but then it also loaded the already existing jQuery along with it. So now there are two files being called, version 1.12 and 3.3.

How do I just get the one that is already there to load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first block of code, from your question, is all you need. 'jquery' is specified in `wp_register_script` function call as dependency. When you enqueue your 'custom_script', 'jquery' will be enqueued also.

Comment: In the first block of code, it a custom script, not jquery.

Comment: If I don't try to load on my own jQuery, no jQuery is called.

Comment: But jquery is specified in wp_register_script as dependency, and will be enqueued as well

Comment: OK I see, it was loading in the header and I was looking in the footer for it. None of my scripts is working though.

Comment: Then you'll have to debug your scripts.